# Importing SSL Certificate (from Network Solutions) to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

**Current Situation:** I host all my files on an AWS EC2 instance but recently I bought a domain name from Network Solutions and pointed that domain name to my ec2 instance. Also, I got an SSL certificate issued from Network Soltuions for that specific domain name.

**Question:** How do I upload an SSL Certificate to AWS. Now, I know that we can use AWS Certificate Manager or AWS Load Balancers to import an SSL Certificate but it asks me for a Certificate Private Key which I have no idea what it is. I am sure I did not get any private key from Network Solutions. All I have are the 4 .crt files and the certificate chain.

Comment: Do you still want to host with EC2 or you can take it to cloudfront? Moving to cloudfront gets you free SSL from Amazon and you don't need to deal with certs.

Comment: Network Solutions definitely provided you with the private key. Maybe you didn't download it, but they provided it. Or maybe one of those `.crt` files is the private key. If you don't have it or if you are confused about what you have you should contact Network Solutions about it. If you are trying to import the certificate into AWS Certificate Manager note that you can only use that with a Load Balancer or CloudFront. And if you are doing that, then it's easier (and free) to just request a new SSL certificate from AWS Certificate Manager.

Comment: @MarkB Right! I tried finding if one of those .crt is my private key. But, did not really get any positive leads. Also using that SSL certificate involved converting the files to .pem encoded files (for AWS) so, I just got a new certificate issued through Amazon Certificate Manager. I am working with Amazon Load Balancer right now.

Question: I already set up a classic Load Balancer with HTTP and HTTPS configuration. The SSL certificate issued by Amazon now says "IN USE - YES" but my instance and/or domain name still says not secure. Any idea why?

Comment: Your instance will not be using SSL if you hit it directly. Your domain name should be pointing to the DNS name of the load balancer, not directly to your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get the Private key from Network if you want to use the one they provided. Or like others are saying you can provision one for free from ACM and let AWS manage it, through they do not give you the private key.

> .CRT = The CRT extension is used for certificates. The certificates may be encoded as binary DER or as ASCII PEM. The CER and CRT extensions are nearly synonymous.  Most common among *nix systems

https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them

You can use the CLI or the console to import Certificates in ACM

```
$ aws acm import-certificate --certificate file://Certificate.pem
                             --certificate-chain file://CertificateChain.pem
                             --private-key file://PrivateKey.pem
```

The following example shows how to import a certificate using the AWS Management Console.

1. Open the ACM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home.
2. Choose Import a certificate.
3. Do the following:

   a. For Certificate body, paste the PEM-encoded certificate to import.

   b. For Certificate private key, paste the PEM-encoded, unencrypted
   private key that matches the certificate's public key.

   c. (Optional) For Certificate chain, paste the PEM-encoded certificate
   chain.
4. Choose Review and import.
5. Review the information about your certificate, then choose Import.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-api-cli.html

Routing SSL traffic to your Domain.

1. [Create an ELB and Assign the Cert to a Listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html)
2. [Set your Domain name to the ELB.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html)